# iOS - Can't Build on Device but Simulator on Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, libxml2, xcode4.6

I'm now using `Xcode 4.6` but cannot build my app on a device but perfectly working on simulator. It is looking my `lbxml2`, I already followed the solutions given by other users like adding `"${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2"` to `Header Search Paths` under `Build Setting`, include in `Link Binary With Libraries` under `Build Phases` but still no luck.

Before I switched to `Xcode 4.6`, it was building on `Xcode 4.5`. So, I really don't know what is wrong.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

I am getting this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang-real++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode 4.6/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting from Xcode when trying to build for the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to link your library in?

A "-lxml2" line in your build settings?

When I add my dylibs to my project, I usually do it the way you see in my screenshot.

Try this and see if it works for you also:

[image: Add a library this way]

Comment: Where to add the `-lxml2`? I'm adding it on build phase.

Comment: take out "-lxml2" and add in the dylib into the "Frameworks" files and see what happens.

Comment: does this really fixing your issue ? i know it is too old..but currently i am facing the same issue with xcode 4.6